# ASP.NET Core REST API with React SPA

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web application that hosts a REST API. I'm attempting to add a React-based Single-Page Application (SPA) to the server but the application is *not* using [MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

When I enable a `Router` my app no longer loads. If I disable the `Router` and only host the static app, it loads correctly, but of course it can't communicate with the web API.

I've also sucessfully hosted my SPA using Python's built-in web server and using a simple file server written in Go, but, again, then it can't "talk" to my API without running separate services and or proxying/redirecting URLs. My goal is a single, C# application that can serve both the API and the static user interface.

Here are relevant portions of my `MyStartup` class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRouting();
    services.AddLogging();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
    });

    app.UseRouter(buildRoutes(app));
}

private IRouter buildRoutes(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // TODO: Figure out how to add a default (and versioned) API base URL to the Router...
    string url(string path) {
        return $"api/{path}";
    }

    RouteBuilder routeBuilder = new RouteBuilder(app, new RouteHandler(null));

    /// Notify API
    routeBuilder.MapGet(url("status"), GetControllerStatus);

    routeBuilder.MapPost(url("heartbeat"), GotHeartbeat);

    routeBuilder.MapGet(url("items/{id}"), httpCtx =>  {
        string id  = httpCtx.GetRouteValue("id").ToString();
        return RetrieveItem(httpCtx, id);
    });

    // ... More routes ...

    return routeBuilder.Build();
}
```

and my `Main` class contains this excerpt:

```
IWebHost host =
    new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseUrls("http://*:11111")
        .UseStartup<MyStartup>()
        .Build();

host.Run();
```

I've investigated the following tools and tutorials, but they all seem to require different approaches using MVC:

- https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-2.0#routing-helpers
- https://github.com/bradymholt/aspnet-core-react-template/tree/master/api
- https://github.com/aspnet/templating/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates/content/React-CSharp/Startup.cs
- https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/973#issuecomment-303766597 (very relevant!)
- https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1150 (very relevant!)

Is it possible to host an SPA from an ASP.NET Core application that isn't using MVC?

Comment: The React template for ASP.NET Core 2.1 (you need Visual Studio 2017.8 Preview) has this exact structure: a React SPA loaded through index.html and the API that does not use MVC

Comment: The React template app in ASP.NET Core 2.1 explicitly uses MVC (the one described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)). Could you share a link to the template you're referring to? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what from that link makes you think the application uses MVC? "The project template creates an ASP.NET Core app and a React app. The ASP.NET Core app is intended to be used for data access, authorization, and other server-side concerns. The React app, residing in the ClientApp subdirectory, is intended to be used for all UI concerns."

Comment: I shared the link that describes the template. I have created and opened the React template app in Visual Studio using ASP.NET Core 2.1. `Startup.cs` calls `app.UseMvc...`, and there is no sign of `app.UseRouter`. My application uses a `Router`, as described above.

Comment: Did you install Visual Studio 2017 Preview update 8? That's **the only** version of VS that generates the React template without MVC